# Crear rama a partir de otra mediante comandos (git)

Tags: git, git-merge

Dentro de mi proyecto estoy realizando unas tareas en una rama (rama_A), que fue ramificada de la rama principal del proyecto (master). Ahora **necesito crear una nueva rama, que nazca a partir de la rama_A** (pongamos rama_A_ramificación)

**¿Cómo puedo crear una nueva rama a partir de otra ya creada con comandos?**

Cuando trabajo desde master, realizo la creación con:

```
git checkout -b "rama_A"
```

¿Sería correcto situarme en rama_A (en este caso ya estoy con -b) y partir de ahí hacer el mismo paso?

Quedaría:

```
git checkout rama_A
git checkout -b "rama_A_ramificación"
```

Y una última cosa, para mergear después esas dos ramas (rama_A y rama_A_ramificación), es decir, guardar los cambios de la ramificación de A a la propia rama_A, ¿Cómo debo hacerlo? ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu deducción es correcta.
El procedimiento habitual con Git es tener dos ramas principales (Master y Development) y habitualmente una rama por desarrollador (para equipos de desarrollo), y cada desarrollador ramificaría su rama personal según varios criterios (funcionalidad, tarea, hito...).
En desarrollos simples se utiliza Development como rama principal de desarrollo y se ramifica según los criterios antes comentados. En tu caso tu **rama_A** sería *Development* o la rama de desarrollo por lo que sería correcto utilizar `git checkout -b rama_A_ramificación`. Si utilizas el bash de Git asegurate con `git branch` que estás en la rama de la que quieres que la nueva rama herede.

Con esta estructura podrías desarrollar funcionalidades en tu **rama_A** y en tu **rama_A_Ramificación** y puedes *mergear* los cambios persistiendo tu ramificación (add -A, commit -m "", push) y haciendo pull desde la rama en la que quieras mergear:
*Desde rama_A_ramificación*

```
git add -A
git commit -m "New functionality"
git push origin rama_A_ramificacion
git checkout rama_A
git pull origin rama_A_ramificacion
```

o utilizar el comando `git merge rama_A_ramificación` desde tu *rama_A*.

Answer (score 2):

El comando `git branch ＜new-branch＞` permite crear una rama nueva rama.

Una vez creada, puedes usar `git checkout new_branch` para cambiar a esa rama.

El comando `git checkout` acepta el argumento `-b`, que creará la nueva rama y cambiará a ella al instante.

El comando siguiente crea la rama `<new-branch>` basandose en `<existing-branch>` y se cambia a `＜new-branch＞` al instante

**git checkout -b ＜new-branch＞ ＜existing-branch＞**